# Is it possible to view a webpage that is being edited in vscode.dev?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

If we are using vscode in the browser to edit an html file or project, is there a way to view the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeSwing is an extension that works in vscode.dev that does this.

Description: Interactive coding playground for building web applications (aka swings).
Id: codespaces-contrib.codeswing
VS Marketplace Link:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=codespaces-Contrib.codeswing

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you mean.

On my chromebook I use vscode.dev in one browser tab, and then just drag and drop the .html file in to an empty browser tab and it can run Vanilla JS, CSS3, and HTML without anything else.

Refresh after each save, or install a live server. You could also have VScode running node, or whatever, in the background and just edit in vscode.dev, but that seems a bit excessive.

(Before I was using Crostini to run VScode on my chromebook and it would sometimes become very slow, buggy, or keep flickering (gpu style), and I'd have to restart/kill crostini to fix it, so finding vscode.dev has really helped when I can't find time to get to my workstation.)

Comment: Thank you.  Do you mean you save the file locally, then open that in your browser?

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest way imo.

Comment: I found the answer: CodeSwing is an extension that works in vscode.dev that does this.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=codespaces-Contrib.codeswing